# Visual Studio Code tasks & debugging

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

I use a gulp task to run my node.js unit tests, and a [VSCode task](http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) to execute this gulp task. Now I'd like to debug my tests. Unfortunately, VSCode ignores break points when running the task. Apparently it uses the default *run* mode instead of the *debug* mode when starting a task.

Is there a way to tell VSCode to execute a task in *debug* mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for mocha tests: https://gist.github.com/paambaati/54d33e409b4f7cf059cc#gistcomment-1835655

In other cases you have to create a [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) to debug you code. In this configuration you can set the `preLaunchTask` property to the name of your gulp task. If your task is configured as `isWatching` you might also need to configure a [`problemMatcher`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher) otherwise the task will not allow the debugger to start before the task ends.

Comment: I added a new entry to my launch.json and set preLaunchTask to the name of my test task. Now when I run this launch config, the tests are executed, but without debugging; after the tests are finished, the main app is started with debugging enabled. In my test task, I explicitly set isWatching to false. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I have added a sample for mocha tests to my answer. In this case the tests are started via launch.json and not by a task. does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks, this works :) Even though it feels like a bit of a hack: it *should* be possible to just run a task in debug mode; however, your solution seems to be the best VS.Code currently can provide.